Java. Does file-encoding affect file-comparison at the level of pure bytes?
I'm using the following to compare the content of two supposedly identical files. I've read that—at least with respect to textual files, like TXT or HTML—the encoding of a file affects how a file's hexadecimal-sequence is translated into characters: i.e., for the same hexadecimal-sequence, a file encoded in UTF-8 will display different content to one encoded in ASCII. Does file-encoding affect my code below at all? or does it not, as I am comparing the files' contents at the basic level of bytes, whereat hexadecimal-sequences are not concerned?
Edit: I'm using this code to compare two supposedly identical files of any file type and of any file size.
bin_1 = new BufferedInputStream(file_input_stream_1); 
bin_2 = new BufferedInputStream(file_input_stream_2);

byte[] barr_1 = new byte[8192];
byte[] barr_2 = new byte[8192]; 

while(bin_1.available() > 0){

    bin_1.read(barr_1); bin_2.read(barr_2);

    if(Arrays.equals(barr_1, barr_2) == false){
        break;
    }

    else{

        barr_1 = new byte[8192]; 
        barr_2 = new byte[8192];
        continue;

    }
    
}


What are you trying to do? If you are just trying to see if two files have the same bytes, then you don't need to think about encoding. If you are trying to see if two files have the same characters, then encoding does matter.

Files.mismatch handles byte comparison. What you have shown won't work. The read calls return number of bytes actually read which may be different to each other, and available() is no use here as loop exit  condition. No need to reallocate the arrays.

@Sweeper User Thomas' answer below says that, yes, encoding does matter though.

What they say is correct, and doesn't contradict what I said. I think they misunderstood your question. Their answer assumes that you want to compare the characters, then comparing bytes like you have shown would not work.

@DuncG So if I run it on two identical files, and print to the console the contents of the two byte [] s on each loop, the print-outs are identical, which implies that it's doing what I'm expecting it to do: i.e., compare byte-chunks of the two files at once and check for parity. I haven't had the available() Exit-Condition fail yet: when the first file has no more bytes left to be read, the code exits as I expect it to; could you elaborate on why you say it wouldn't work? Reallocating the byte []s ensures that no bytes from the previous loop remain.

@Oh, I see. No, I am NOT concerned with the character-output of the files; I am only concerned that the byte-content of each is identical. To be clear, do I understand it correctly that conversion to hexadecimal-sequences, and thence to character-output, is a process that is of no concern when just comparing the byte-contents of two files?

@william Its flawed implementation as you have not accounted for when read(barr_1) returns a different length to read(barr_2). The values of available() are irrelevant.

@DuncG Well, regarding read() on the two streams returning different data, that condition is handled in the next step when the byte[] s are checked: if the byte [] s are different in content then the loop breaks; so I can't see how the code doesn't handle that condition. Also,  could you explain how available() is irrelevant? it should simply tell the loop whether there is more data left to be read, and it seems to do that successfully; I can't see how omitting available() would not break the code...

Short answer: NO!
No, file-encoding does not come into play when you compare files on byte-level.
Why? Because you read the files byte by byte and compare them byte by byte. Ok, for performance reasons, you want to read larger chunks, and not only single bytes. But this is done under the hood for you by BufferedInputStream, so the code is just working on the bytes.
InputStream::read does not interpret the byte it reads in any way.
var isEqual = true;
try( final var inputStream1 = new BufferedInputStream( fileInputStream1 );
    final var inputStream2 = new BufferedInputStream( fileInputStream2 ) )
{
  ReadLoop: while( isEqual )
  {
    final var v1 = inputStream1.read();
    final var v2 = inputStream2.read();
    isEqual = v1 == v2;
    if( v1 == EOF ) break ReadLoop;
  }  // ReadLoop:  
}

It would be different if you would use an instance of Reader instead of an InputStream. A Reader assumes a text file and does the transformation based on the encoding.
From the Javadoc for FileInputStream:

FileInputStream is meant for reading streams of raw bytes such as image data. For reading streams of characters, consider using FileReader.

"File-encoding" is a concept that is only relevant when explicitly dealing with textual data – when talking about files, for "streams of characters" (aka. text files).

You don't need the label.

@DuncG – I know. But first it does not harm, and second it shows neatly where the loop body starts and ends.

I wouldn't say neatly, but the code solves the problem.

@tquadrat Thank you for the additional answer there. So even considering that encoding DOES affect TEXTUAL files insofar as interpretation of bytes, am I still right to assume that even for TEXTUAL files encoding still does not matter when simply comparing bytes, as both my own and your code is written to do? that the encoding only matters later when it comes to trying to interpret those bytes?

@william – Right, on the lowest level, files are just a bunch of bytes on a storage media – and they can be compared on that level easily, as you asked for. Whether a file is holding textual data, an image, a database or executable code is an interpretation of those bytes that happened on higher levels. Assume you want to test whether a JPEG and a PNG shows the same person: this requires the interpretation of the respective files and their transformation to a comparable format. The text-encoding is "jpeg" or "gif", but for text files, and in same way needed only for higher level comparisons.

@tquadrat That's very clear and actually pretty interesting. Thanks a lot.


...basic level of bytes, whereas hexadecimal-sequences are not concerned

I think you have a misconception here. Bytes are groups of 8 bits which are expressed in hexadecimal to save some space (e.g. FF would be the equivalent to the byte value 11111111). So those are essentially the same.

Edit: I'm using this code to compare two supposedly identical files of any file type and of any file size.

With your edit the question changes a little. However, others may be directed here when looking for text file comparison so let me split the answer into 2 parts:
Comparing arbitrary files at the byte level
Files can generally be compared at the byte level because files (as of our current state of tech) are just sequences of bytes.
Hence you can do it the way you posted, i.e. read blocks of bytes from both files and compare those (this would be more performant than reading single bytes). This could be generalized to reading blocks of bytes from any byte stream so it would be applicable to downloads and other forms of stream too.
Alternatively already existing and well-tested file comparison methods e.g.

Java's own Files.mismatch() (as of Java 12)
Google Guava's Files.equal()
Apache Commons IO's PathUtils.fileContentEquals()

Comparing supposedly identical text files
When it comes to text files the term "supposedly identical" gets a somewhat different meaning. In this case the files might have identical text content but they might differ at the byte level.
That's where encoding becomes important. As long as your text only contains ASCII characters there might be a chance that common encodings will result in the same bytes as UTF-8 and Latin-1 share the same basic sequence.
However, other encodings may be totally different.
As an example use the text "stackoverflow".

Latin-1: 73 74 61 63 6B 6F 76 65 72 66 6C 6F 77
UTF-8: 73 74 61 63 6B 6F 76 65 72 66 6C 6F 77
UTF-16 big endian: 0073 0074 0061 0063 006B 006F 0076 0065 0072 0066 006C 006F 0077

Also note that there are UTF-8 files with and without BOM (byte order mark) so you'd need to adjust your comparison accordingly. That means the following hex sequences basically represent the same content:

Without BOM: 73 74 61 63 6B 6F 76 65 72 66 6C 6F 77
With BOM: EF BB BF 73 74 61 63 6B 6F 76 65 72 66 6C 6F 77

You now might ask: How do I compare those files then?
Well, you'd best compare them at the character level since Java uses one character code internally. However, you'd need to know the encoding of the files to tell Java how to convert the bytes into characters when loading the file - and you might still have to look for the UTF-8 BOM since Java will most likely try to read that as characters.
If you don't know the encoding you could try to detect it using a library like Apache Tika, ICU4J or juniversalchardet. Those libraries would read the files and try to "guess" the encoding which means confidence may vary.

What you said is not wrong, but irrelevant in regards to the question: the TO wants to compare on the byte level (the raw bytes), so the way how to interpret those bytes as characters does not matter at all.

@tquadrat with the OP's last edit you're right - however the question may still be read by others and it may be confusing because the way this question is formulated in gives the impression OP want's to compare "supposedly identical" text files (whereas "supposedly identical" might mean "same content"). I'll update the answer though to reflect that.

The headline had been "Java. Does file-encoding affect file-comparison at the level of pure bytes?" right from the beginning …

@tquadrat that's true but the headline alone doesn't explain what the OP wants to do. Is it compare any files? Then why should encoding be mentioned? Is it compare text files at byte level? That's where encoding matters.

@Thomas Thank you for your detailed answer there, and for the existing file-checking methods. Most of what you've written assures me that encoding DOES NOT matter when checking ANY file-type at the level of bytes; however, in your most recent reply to the user tquadrat you say "Is it compare text files at byte level? That's where encoding matters." Up until you said that, I thought that the code I posted would work on textual files like TXT and HTML just as well as any other file-type, regardless of encoding...

@william that's what I wanted to point out with my answer's update: you can compare any file at a binary level, even text files. If you have 2 text files that contain the same text but use different encoding those are different at a binary level though. So if you expect "equal text content = files are equal", then you need the encoding. If you're just after "exact same content no matter what it is" then byte level comparison is sufficient.

@ Got it. Thanks. I can use the code in the OP to compare the byte-content of any two files, even TXT files that have different encoding. So I guess in reality it would be very unlikely to actually have two TXT files that have the exact same byte-content yet are encoded differently, as while one might read-out sensibly to the screen, the other probably wouldn't.

@william yes, that's right. Exact same byte content yet different encoding would result in different text being "extracted" (by "decoding" the bytes). You might still encode a file that only contains ASCII chars using Latin-1 and properly decode using UTF-8 because the ASCII portion is the same - so the encoding wouldn't matter in those cases either.

@william Rather than add another long comment, this outlines a few problems with InputStream byte vs byte comparison you have used. I'll delete if no help to you.

Loop condition should not use available() as available() can potentially return 0
for InputStream before the end of stream, so your loop could exit before having checked all the bytes of both streams.


Returns an estimate of the number of bytes that can be read (or skipped over) from this input stream without blocking, which may be 0, or 0 when end of stream is detected.


if first stream is size N * 8192, you would exit the loop when bin_1.available() is zero, but without knowing whether the second stream has matching size - it could be longer.

Using read(byte[] arr) is also an issue. It returns number of bytes actually copied into arr and could potentially be smaller than the byte[] arr.length even though there are more bytes to read, or returns -1 if stream is ended / end-of-file which you need to look for to know when to stop reads.


When reading identical files (perhaps from different filesystems), the returned size read len1 might be different to len2 leading you to incorrectly assume the files are different, as Arrays.equals(barr_1, barr_2) would be false:
int len1 = bin_1.read(barr_1);
int len2 = bin_2.read(barr_2);

Since JDK12 -  there is a variant of read which will re-read until the length you specify - so it is better to use readNBytes instead of read(byte[]) when reading two streams you compare, and check for -1 / EOF.

You don't need new BufferedInputStream( ... ) here as you use read(byte[]) into your own byte[]. Thus the built-in buffer provided by BufferedInputStream is unnecessary/unused.

The easy solution for byte-by-byte comparison is mentioned in some comments and other answers. From JDK12 just use Files.mismatch(Path,Path) which returns -1 for matched content. The current source shows this:
/**
 * Section of JDK22 Source for java.nio.file.Files
 * public static long mismatch(Path path, Path path2)
 */ 
byte[] buffer1 = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
byte[] buffer2 = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
try (InputStream in1 = Files.newInputStream(path);
     InputStream in2 = Files.newInputStream(path2)) {
    long totalRead = 0;
    while (true) {
        int nRead1 = in1.readNBytes(buffer1, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
        int nRead2 = in2.readNBytes(buffer2, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);

        int i = Arrays.mismatch(buffer1, 0, nRead1, buffer2, 0, nRead2);
        if (i > -1) {
            return totalRead + i;
        }
        if (nRead1 < BUFFER_SIZE) {
            // we've reached the end of the files, but found no mismatch
            return -1;
        }
        totalRead += nRead1;
    }
    

You can easily package this up for use in older JDK, or enhance it to handle InputStream directly so that it would work with streams from servlets / sockets etc:
public static long mismatch(InputStream in1, InputStream in2)

If you need to compare characters in files of different encodings, you will need to decode and compare char by char. See Thomas answer

Thanks for your help there. I had a lot of further questions, so I put them all in a TXT-file and put them on Dropbox for you https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/3d8j7af2two94lvfprw3t/further-quesitons-190424.txt?rlkey=q5iolvkl2xzzkesowa4v65qhc&st=i1e3vnkc&dl=0

@william All files are stored as series of bytes (accessed with Input/OutputStream). Characters of text files need to be decoded/encoded as bytes when loaded/saved (accessed with Reader/Writer).
